# Send cookie cross domain with angular 2 HTTP get

Tags: angular

How do I send a cookie with Angular 2 cross domain:

```
  const headers = new Headers({ 'Cookie': 'test=me'});

  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers });

  return this.http.get(this.specialUrl, options )
    .map( (res: Response ) => res.json());
```

I can't see it in the headers:

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: api.crm.test
Origin: http://front-end:4200
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://front-end:4200/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101     Firefox/60.0
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

UPDATE. TRIED;

```
  const headers = new Headers({ 'Cookie': 'test=me'});

  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers, withCredentials: true});

return this.http.get(this.specialUrl, options )
  .map( (res: Response ) => res.json());
```

Everything compiles.

Comment: Use `withCredentials: true`

Comment: See my update :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `headers` parameter name. Try this way:

```
const headers = new Headers({ 'Cookie': 'test=me'});
return this.http.get(this.specialUrl, { headers: headers} )
    .map((res: Response ) => res.json());
```